# Does implicit conversion force index scans instead of seeks?

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I'm joining table `A` against tables `B` and `C`. All three tables have similar columns and indexes, and `B` and `C` have about the same number of rows. But `A` and `B` have indexes on `nvarchar` columns while `C` has indexes on `varchar` columns.

Tested separately, joining on `B` is 30-60 times faster than joining on `C`. (4 seconds vs. 2-4 minutes.) Looking at the execution plan, `B` uses an index seek while `C` uses an index scan. The details for the join on `C` mention implicit conversion of the `varchar` columns, while the join on `B` mentions no such conversion. **Is this why it's using a scan instead of a seek, and is this probably why it's so slow?** (Another potential issue: the index scan on `C` has an estimated number of executions of 1, but the actual number of executions is around 8500.)

`C` is static historical data, so I could alter the columns and rebuild the indexes if it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes implicit conversions may result in index scans instead of seeks.  Data is converted to the data type with the higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  As you've seen in this case the `VARCHAR` column of table `c` is converted to an `NVARCHAR` value.  The implicit conversion protects against losing data during conversion, i.e. `NVARCHAR` columns can hold significantly more distinct characters than `VARCHAR` so the implicit conversion of `VARCHAR` from table `C` ensures that all the values from table C will be preserved. 
 Details on specific implicit conversion scenarios are further outlined [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatform/2018/01/29/implicit-conversions-ouch/).  If you have the option and this won't have any negative implications elsewhere, I'd suggest making this column in table `C` an `NVARCHAR` data type.

Comment: Regarding your last point, I assume you mean `NVARCHAR`. I made that change (tediously dropping and recreating a bunch of indexes and constraints) and confirmed that my query now runs 30x faster.

Comment: That's correct.  I updated my post to resolve the typo.  Glad it helped the query.